# Sudden spike in close votes and not enough reviewers

Tags: discussion, review

As of right now, there are 32 questions on the main site that have been voted to be closed. The peak today was 42 questions (which occurred about 3 hours ago). Looking at the stats for the close votes, many people with 3k+ reputation have already reviewed 20 times, and the other reviewers all seem to have 10+ reviews.

My question is this: is it possible to have the review limit set higher than 20 per day? This would be very helpful to the review stack, which is consistently clogged up.

Comment: I fear that a higher limit would encourage automaton behaviour.

Comment: Moderators have access to some review statistics. @André is correct in that there are reviewers who have a very clear bias in favor of keeping open or closing. The presence of such a bias seems to correlate with review speed (surprise!). By and large reviewers are acting responsibly. Among the reviewers who have given an opinion on at least 30 posts in the close queue and who spend less than 15 seconds per post (last 30 day stats), there is one user with 99% bias in favor of keeping open and another with 93% bias in favor of closing.

Comment: If we include users with less reviews, say down to 10, then a totalitarian closer makes the cut. But I would say that the steeply biased reviewers are not a major concern.

Answer (score 5):

**Probably not.**

The idea of raising or removing the daily review limit has come up many times in discussions about Stack Overflow (which usually has a close vote review queue in the thousands, getting to ~100k in the past). It's one of several suggestions put forward to to try to trim the SO close vote queue.

But I don't think the SE Staff/Devs are too keen to raise the limit. For example, [this answer on Meta.se by SE Dev Anna Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195827/226928):

> We have considered raising the number of reviews available to people, likely scaled with the number of their reviews that resulted in the community-approved action (“leave open” on questions that didn't get closed, etc.). However, we want more people doing fewer reviews a day to spread the work around rather than just overload the already highly engaged reviewers to ensure that nobody burns out and that as many people get involved as possible.

I've seen similar comments scattered around various Meta sites to the same effect.

Given that the review limit didn't move on Stack Overflow for a tens-of-thousands-strong queue, I think it's unlikely they'd do it for Math.se.

Comment: It did move from 20 to 40 on SO. Here it's 20. But otherwise I agree.

Comment: @Behaviour Did it? I missed that, but fair enough. (I don't have review privileges on SO, so I learn this stuff from Meta posts.)